# Warning in Samtools installation

Tags: installation, samtools

I recently installed samtools by compiling it using gcc with the command 'make' in linux.

Everything went smoothly apart from 2 warnings that appeared:

(1) bam_reheader.c:36:19: warning: variable 'old' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]

(2) kprobaln.c:78:21: warning: variable 'is_diff' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]

Would anyone know what these warnings mean and if they this might become an potential issue in running samtools?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you've already figured this out (or at least part of it), but occasionally people have variables left in their code that don't get used. These show up in warnings during the compile process, but are harmless. They are more for the developer.